# Sed and capturing groups struggle

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a text file that looks like this

```
(111)1111111
(111)-111-1111
(111)111-1111
111.111.1111
```

that I'm using to practice group capturing with regex and sed. The command I am running on the file (called test) is

```
sed 's/(?\(\d(3}\)[-.]?\(\d{3}\)[-.]?\(\d{4}\)/\1\2\3' test > output
```

Expecting the output that is just all 1's on every line. However, what I'm getting is just the entire file with no changes. What's going wrong?

Comment: `?` needs backslash quoting.

Comment: Thanks! That did not fix the problem however but now I know that was part of the problem.

Comment: It also neds a final `/`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In standard basic regex, `(?\(\d(3}\)[-.]?` means:

```
a literal left parenthesis
a literal question mark
(start of a group)
a literal character 'd'
a literal left parenthesis 
the number '3'
a literal closing brace
(end of group)
a dash or a dot
a question mark
```

i.e., this will print `x`:

```
echo '(?d(3}-?' |sed 's/(?\(\d(3}\)[-.]?/x/'
```

You're very likely to want `sed -E` to enable extended regular expressions (ERE), and to then use `(` and `)` for grouping, and `\(` and `\)` for literal parenthesis.

Also note that `\d` is part of Perl regexes, not standard ones, and while GNU sed supports some `\X` escapes, they're not standard (and I don't think it supports `\d`). Same for `\?`, GNU sed supports it in BRE to mean what `?` means in ERE, but it's not standard.

With all that in mind:

```
$ echo '(123)-456-7890' | sed -E 's/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-.]?([0-9]{3})[-.]?([0-9]{4})/\1\2\3/'
1234567890
```

Though you might almost as well just brute force it and just remove everything but the digits:

```
$ echo '(123)-456-7890' | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'
1234567890
```

(that would of course also accept stuff like `(123)-4.5-6-7a8b9c0`...)

See also:

- The [`regex(7)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html)
- [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/170373)

Comment: Good answer, just a tiny remark: According to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), *the interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped backslash is undefined*, so while `\d` is likely to match a literal `d`, you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it below awk command too

```
echo "123-45-6789-10101"| awk '{gsub("[^0-9]","",$1);print }'
```

Output

```
12345678910101
```

Answer (score 0):

[ilkkachu described](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439855/116858) very well why your regular expression does not work with `sed` (it's in a dialect not supported).

Here is an alternate way that just deletes the characters that are not `1`:

```
sed 's/[^1]//g' file
```

To use groups, you may do something like

```
sed -E 's/([^1]*)(1+)([^1]*)/\2/g' file
```

That is, match a non-empty string of ones delimited on either side by a possibly empty string of non-ones, and replace all of that with the matched string of ones.

Change `1` to `[0-9]` and `[^1]` to `[^0-9]` to handle all digits.